# bootstrap won't take effect cause the provided path is wrong

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

project codebase url: https://github.com/ismailalabou/service-mvc

[image: browser devtools snapshot]

I need help in order to fix this.
thanks

[image: scope]

Comment: the correct path is: "http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Answer (score 0):

never mind I figure it out
I got lucky
[image: yay]